# change simpleXML attribute name

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```html
<Root>
...
    <A CHANGE_THIS="Dont_ChengeME">
        <B></B>  
    </A>
...
</Root>
```

trying to change the attribute name of element A
to something of my choice, using php's simpleXML
API. here's what i've done:

```html
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($xmldom);
    $query = "root/A[@]";
    $result = $xml->xpath($query);  
       if(!empty($result))
         $result['CHANGE_THIS'] = "Blalalalal";       //i believe this is where am doing it wrong
```

All attempts failed. any idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the attribute's name or its value?

Comment: You can not change an attribute name, remove the attribute and add a new one with them same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, assuming you don't require the use of XPath:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmldom);
$result = $xml->{'A'}->attributes();
if(!empty($result)) {
  $preserve_this = $result['CHANGE_THIS'];
  $result->addAttribute('Blalalalal', $preserve_this);
  unset($result['CHANGE_THIS']);
}
```

Comment: thanks. ur approach worked and has thought me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$xml->A['changed_value'] = $xml->A['CHANGE_THIS'];
unset($xml->A['CHANGE_THIS']);
```

The reason that your attempt didn't work is that

```
$result['CHANGE_THIS'] = "Blalalalal";
```

is assigning the string "Blalalala" to the array element which is indexed by 'CHANGE_THIS'. I don't know of any simpler way to effectively change the index for an array element except to copy the element into a new element with the desired index (i.e. 'changed_value') and then unset the original array element.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the OP's question. If you can't comment due to low reputation, then just be patient until you've built up enough to post comments.

Comment: @Havelock its the attribute name, not the value i need to change. please give me a light to manipulate the $result if you can. thanks !

Comment: @Lukasz: I have edited my answer, just wanted to get the necessary info to devise a solution.